# Where is the DATA_DUMP_DIR in sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to import a .dmp file using the Data Pump Import tool in oracle sql developer.

I'm connected to an oracle database running in a container on my local machine.

When I get to the step where I specify where the dump file is to import, where should I place the .dmp file?

[image: data pump import]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DATA_PUMP_DIR` is a [default Oracle directory object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html#GUID-EEB32B50-8A00-40B0-8787-CC2C8BA05DC5). It isn't part of SQL Developer; the import tool is really just giving you a GUI equivalent of running `impdp` from the command line.

You can find the operating system location that Oracle directory object points to by querying the data dictionary:

```
select directory_path from all_directories where directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';
```

The path that returns is on the database server (in your case that'll be inside your container too), and your dump file needs to go there.

You might want to create additional directory objects pointing to other locations, and grant suitable privileges to users to be able to access them; but they all need to be on the DB server and read/writable by the Oracle process owner on that server.

(They could be remote filesystems mounted on the server, they don't necessarily have to be local storage, but that's another issue and more operating-system specific. Again, in your case, you might be able to share a folder on your local machine with the container, if you don't want to copy the file into the container.)

Comment: Thanks Alex, prefect!!